# How do I do a basic implementation of Delegation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift2

I am trying to get my head around delegation and am stripping it down to a basic implementation. I've came up with this, but the delegate function never gets called. Could anyone shed some light?

```
protocol MyDelegate{
    func delegatedFunction (a:String)
}

class DelegatorClass {
    var delegate: MyDelegate?
    func callDelegate() {
        delegate?.delegatedFunction("hello")
    }
}

class DelegateClass: MyDelegate {
    func delegatedFunction (a:String){
        print(a)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to associate variable "delegate" with the DelegateClass before you proceed to call. In this case you will be calling a function over a nil value which is a runtime error!

Comment: Delegation is similar to interface based composition of objects. This is a way of decoupling objects and responsibilities. You might be able to better appreciate if you read first 3 chapters of Head First with Design Patterns.

Answer (score 7):

```
let myDelegatorObj = DelegatorClass()
myDelegatorObj.delegate = DelegateClass()
myDelegatorObj.callDelegate()
```

Point is before you call `callDelegate()` you need to assign the `delegate`. To check your delegation working, you can initialize the `DelegatorClass` with the delegate.

```
class DelegatorClass {
    var delegate: MyDelegate? = DelegateClass()
    func callDelegate() {
        delegate?.delegatedFunction("hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go. However I would specify that the first example and the second example are different approaches to activate the delegation. First example is most versitile as it permits to use a different istance of a delegate class, without hardcoding it in the delegator class

Comment: @MarcoPappalardo you are right. 2nd example is only for test.

Answer (score 4):

Using your code, this is the way to properly use delegate.
when you call `callDelegate()`, it will take the reference of the `DelegateClass`, and execute `delegatedFunction()`

```
protocol MyDelegate{
    func delegatedFunction (a:String)
}
```

---

```
class DelegatorClass {
    var delegate: MyDelegate?
    func callDelegate() {
        delegate?.delegatedFunction("hello")
    }
}
```

---

```
class DelegateClass: MyDelegate {
    let my_class= DelegatorClass()
    my_class.delegate = self

    func delegatedFunction (a:String){
        print(a)
    }
}
```

Look at apple protocols documentations for further information.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: This gives these errors:
    let class = DelegatorClass()   //Keyword 'class' cannot be used as an identifier
    class.delegate = self  //Expected declaration

Comment: ups, my bad, I did not tested it, I will edit the post.

Comment: Great, thanks. This line: "my_class.delegate = self" is still giving an Expected declaration error. Any idea why? Should that line be inside the function?

Comment: I don't think it is a good approach to initialize the delegator inside the delegate.

Answer (score 4):

```
protocol MyDelegate{
    func delegatedFunction (a:String)
}

class DelegatorClass {
    var delegate: MyDelegate?
    func callDelegate() {
        delegate?.delegatedFunction("hello")
    }
}

class DelegateClass: MyDelegate {
    func delegatedFunction (a:String){
        print(a)
    }
}
let delegator = DelegatorClass()
delegator.callDelegate() // print nothing, because delegate is nil by default

// set your delegate !!!!!!!
delegator.delegate = DelegateClass()
delegator.callDelegate() // print "hello"
```

It is nothing wrong with your approach, just use it the right way. The point is set delegate variable to some instance of type T conforming to protocol MyDelegate. In your case this is DelegateClass instance.
Generally, T could be almost everything conforming to MyDelegate protocol.

```
struct S:MyDelegate {
    func delegatedFunction(a: String) {
        print("Hello from struct conforming to MyDelegate protocol")
    }
}

delegator.delegate = S()
delegator.callDelegate() // print "Hello from struct conforming to MyDelegate protocol"

delegator.delegate = nil
delegator.callDelegate() // print nothing again :-)
```

Answer (score 3):

Tested and working on a sample playground.

```
import UIKit

protocol MyDelegate {
    func delegatedFunction(a: String)
}

class DelegatorClass {

    var delegate: MyDelegate?

    func callDelegate() {
        delegate?.delegatedFunction("Hello World!")
    }
}

class DelegateClass: MyDelegate {

    let my_class = DelegatorClass()

    init () {
        my_class.delegate = self
    }

    // MyDelegate Protocol implementation
    func delegatedFunction(a: String) {
       print(a)
    }

}
```

To test it out, add the following lines below.

```
let c = DelegateClass()
c.my_class.callDelegate()
```

To explain,

When you create the instance of DelegateClass `c` and it is initialized, the `init` method is executed. The DelegatorClass instance `my_class` member `delegate` now holds a reference to `self` which is the DelegateClass.

Now when the `callDelegate()` method is executed, since the optional variable `delegate` now holds a reference to the DelegateClass instance, it basically calls for the execution of the `delegatedFunction(a: String)` method in it. And hence, the string `a` is printed.

Also note that the reason I've had to put `my_class.delegate = self` inside `init()` is because you can only have instance property declarations outside methods in a class. All functionality should go inside methods.

Hope that the explanation was clear! :)

Answer (score 2):

You nearly had it, you simply forgot to assign the `class DelegateClass` to the `class DelegatorClass` `delegate` property, with a few other tweaks.

Basically, you are telling the `class DelegateClass` to conform to the `protocol MyDelegate`, which means it has to implement `delegatedFunction(a:String)`.  On `class DelegatorClass`, the `delegate` property is expecting to be assigned an object with a type of `protocol MyDelegate`, so that it can call the protocol function against it, hence the importance of assigning `self` to the `delegate` property in `DelegateClass`

```
protocol MyDelegate{
    func delegatedFunction(a:String)
}

class DelegatorClass {
    var delegate: MyDelegate! = nil
    func callDelegate() {
        delegate.delegatedFunction("hello")
    }
}

class DelegateClass: MyDelegate {
    var delegator:DelegatorClass = DelegatorClass()

    init() {
        delegator.delegate = self
        delegator.callDelegate()
    }
    func delegatedFunction (a:String){
        print(a)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An instance of `DelegateClass` needs to set itself as the delegate of an instance of `DelegatorClass`

So, you would have something like :

```
class DelegateClass: MyDelegate {
    func delegatedFunction (a:String){
        print(a)
    }

    func testFunction() {
       var delegator=DelegatorClass()
       delegator.delegate=self
       delegator.callDelegate()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
protocol Delegate{

    func callMe()
    func textMe()
}

@objc protocol DelegateWithOptional: class{

    optional func callMe()
    func textMe()
}

class SomeClass{

    var delegate: Delegate?

   func call(){
      delegate?.callMe()
   }

   func text(){
      delegate?.textMe()
   }

}

class SomeClass2{

    var delegateWithOptional: DelegateWithOptional?

    func call(){
       delegateWithOptional?.callMe()
    }

    func text(){
       delegateWithOptional?.textMe()
    }
}

class ClassConfirmingToProtocol: SuperClass, Delegate{

    var someClass = SomeClass()
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        someclass.delegate = self
    }

    //must implement this method
    func textMe(){ 
        //do something
    }

    //must implement this method
    func callMe(){  
        //do something
    }

}

class ClassConfirmingToProtocolWithOptional: SuperClass, DelegateWithOptional{

    var someClass2 = SomeClass2()
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        someclass2.delegate = self
    }

    //must implement this method
    func textMe(){ 
        //do something
    }

    //optional to implement this method, i.e. even without this method, its not gonna throw any error
    func callMe(){
        //do something
    }

}
```